# How can I reinstall a module in Unity

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, module, sdk, android-ndk

I am having a problem with Unity hub. I just finished my android game and downloaded the Android build support from unity hub. I don't know what happened but something went wrong and the NDK was not downloaded. I tried to download it again but Unity hub is showing that it is installed and not letting me reinstall it. While I try to build the game it shows NDK not found. So how do I download the JDK, and SDK files in unity?

[This is what unity is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezW9A.png)
[This is shown in preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny3OE.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Show us your preferences (Edit => Preferences => External Tools). There should be specified path to your NDK